# How to check the element is in the vector using std::lower_bound?

Tags: c++, lower-bound

The book, "Effective STL," (by Scott Meyers), suggests that using sorted vectors instead of associative containers is efficient in some conditions. It shows the example of using `std::lower_bound` on `std::vector`. But I found some code in it that looks incorrect:

```
vector<Widget> vw;            // alternative to set<Widget>
 ......                       // Setup phase: lots of
                              // insertions, few lookups

sort(vw.begin(), vw.end());   // end of Setup phase.

Widget w;                     // object for value to look up
 ......                       // start Lookup phase

vector<Widget>::iterator i =
lower_bound(vw.begin(), vw.end(), w);  // lookup via lower_bound;

(1) Below is the weird part!
if (i != vw.end() && !(*i < w))...     // see Item 45 for an explana-
                                       // tion of the"!(*i < w)" test

...                                    // end Lookup phase, start
```

When you see (1), it checks returned iterator from `lower_bound` so that it can tell if `w` is in the vector or not. But I think `!(w < *i)` is right because `std::lower_bound` would be using `less(w, iterating element)`. The `*i` only has two choices: either it is equivalent with `w` (i.e. `w` is an element of vector) or it is greater than `w`. So, as far as I know, to tell these two cases the example code should have used `!(w < *i)`.

Am I correct? Or is there any other reason for above example code?

Comment: Look weird, indeed. What does "Item 45" have to say? (I would just use `... && *i == w`)

Comment: @AdrianMole Item 45 says that using *i == w is a common mistake when using lower_bound because lower_bound is based on not equal but equivalent relation . If you are  not familiar with equivalent relation, you should study it first.

Comment: OK. I can understand why you would want to avoid an `==` operator. But the `!(*i < w)` test *still* looks wrong - because if `std::lower_bound` does **not** return `.end()`, then that expression **will** be (must be) true. That's what the iterated value will be: *not less than*.

Comment: @AdrianMole That's why I think !(*i < w) is wrong. And !(w < *i) looks right to me, but I'm not sure why the book shows example like above.

Comment: See my answer for the "proof".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `!(*i < w)` is clearly wrong (or, at the very least, redundant) because, if the `std::lower_bound()` search does *not* return `vw.end()`, then the result of that test **must be** true. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound):

> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range [first,
> last) that is not less than (i.e. greater or equal to) value, or last
> if no such element is found.

Here's a trivial test that shows it does not correctly determine whether or not a given value is in your vector:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = { 1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
    std::vector<int>::iterator i1 = std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 3); // Present
    if (i1 != vec.end() && !(*i1 < 3)) {
        std::cout << "3 is present\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "3 is missing\n";
    }
    std::vector<int>::iterator i2 = std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 4); // Missing
    if (i2 != vec.end() && !(*i2 < 4)) {
        std::cout << "4 is present\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "4 is missing\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output (clearly wrong):

```
3 is present
4 is present
```

However, changing the second test from the above `!(*i < w)` form, to your `!(w < *i)` works, as shown in the following modified code:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = { 1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
    std::vector<int>::iterator i1 = std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 3); // Present
    if (i1 != vec.end() && !(3 < *i1)) {
        std::cout << "3 is present\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "3 is missing\n";
    }
    std::vector<int>::iterator i2 = std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 4); // Missing
    if (i2 != vec.end() && !(4 < *i2)) {
        std::cout << "4 is present\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "4 is missing\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output (correct):

```
3 is present
4 is missing
```

---

So, unless you have somehow inadvertently misrepresented the code from the book you quote (which I am ***not*** accusing you of doing), then its author should be contacted to point out their error.

Comment: I agree with you. But that means Effective STL has mistake in the example and there is no information about this errata in this book's website. This book is too famous to have unknown errata in it. That's why I ask it here.

Comment: @myoldgrandpa Which is why I have suggested you contact the author/publisher/website to point out the error, so that it can be added to the *errata* list. Note that `!(*i > w)` (i.e. `>` instead of `<`) also works in the case of integers but that may also fall foul of the strict equivalence criteria.

Comment: @myoldgrandpa - The missing errata might depend on *when* the error was  added to the book. In my copy it just says that using `==` is not correct, but offers no code for the alternative. So apparently a later revision.

Comment: .So the purpose of the `lower_bound()` use here is to provide an efficient way to "find" if an element value exists in a container? Is there any data that suggests that using `lower_bound()` is more efficient than using, say [std::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)? That aspect of this question (beyond -- is the book correct -- part) is curious to me. That would seem to be the only reason something like this would be cooked up. Without any data saying you get an, e,g, 30% improvement, makes that aspect of the question a bit unclear...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That is not the point of my question. But to mention it, using sorted vector is more efficient than using map sometimes. If there are bunch of data to be inserted and sorted only once, and read it frequently, you have performance gain to use vector because of locality of data. In addition to it, you talk about std::find. Just check this fact such as std::find vs std::lower_bound = O(N) vs O(logN)

Comment: Thanks. I knew it wasn't the purpose of the question asked, but nevertheless it was one that was lingering unanswered. Many times we get questions that fit into [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  So, by comment, we explore whether the lingering issue is one. A b-search type algorithm on the sorted container seems like it would be another reasonable choice.